# Product of matrix and 3-way tensor in Numpy/Theano

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, theano

I would like to compute the product of a matrix `X` with shape `(a, b)` and a tensor `Y` with shape `(a, b, c)` such that the result `Z` has shape `(a, c)`, and row `i` `(i = 1...a)` of `Z` is the product of row `i` of `X` and the matrix slice `(i, :, :)` of `Y`.

Is there a convenient way to do this in NumPy and Theano, ideally using built-in functions, and without using loops or computing unnecessary matrix products?

Answer (score 1):

With your description, writing an `einsum` expression is easy:

```
In [428]: X=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [429]: Y=np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)

In [431]: np.einsum('ab,abc->ac',X,Y)
Out[431]: 
array([[ 20,  23,  26,  29],
       [200, 212, 224, 236]])
In [432]: _.shape
Out[432]: (2, 4)
```

`np.matmul` or the `@` operator is a little trickier, though probably as fast:

```
In [438]: (X[:,None,:]@Y).squeeze()
Out[438]: 
array([[ 20,  23,  26,  29],
       [200, 212, 224, 236]])
```

The intermediate stage will be (a,1,c) in shape, i.e.

```
(a,1,b)@(a,b,c)=>(a,1,c)   # with sum on b
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect for NumPy. Is there any way to do this with Theano? It seems Theano doesn't have equivalent functions to np.einsum and np.matmul.